# Passing ninject bound object to a class that must have constructor taking 0 params

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject

There's UserRoleProvider class that is using userRepository

```
public class UserRoleProvider : RoleProvider
{
    private IUserRepository userRepo;
    public UserRoleProvider(IUserRepository userRepository)
    {
        userRepo = userRepository;
    }
    ...
}
```

And there's binding method in NinjectDependencyResolver class

```
private void AddBindings()
    {
        kernel.Bind<IUserRepository>().To<EFUserRepository>();
    }
```

In Web.config, I've setted up UserRoleProvider as default RoleProvider

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="UserRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="UserRoleProvider" type="PomocnikPodroznika.WebUI.Infrastructure.Concrete.UserRoleProvider"/>
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
```

I'm getting error saying `UserRoleProvider` doesn't have constructor that takes 0 arguments (and that what config file expects). Is there any way to pass `EFUserRepository` object (using ninject) to `UserRoleProvider` class without passing it through constructor?

Comment: have you tried using the latest [Ninject.Web.Common](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject.Web.Common/) package? I think it should then be able to instantiate types with constructor arguments (your original design).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found solution for my problem.

```
 private IUserRepository userRepo;
        public UserRoleProvider()
        {
            userRepo = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IUserRepository>();
        }
```